# Why are components executed two times for each Gauss-Seidel iteration? (OpenMDAO 2.4.0)

Tags: python, openmdao

I've been using the the `NonLinearBlockGS` as `nonlinear_solver` for my MDO system consisting of `ExplicitComponents` and this works as expected. First I was using this with simple mathematical functions (hence runtime << 1s), but now I'm also implementing a system with multiple explicit components that have runtimes of around one minute or more. That's when I noticed that the `NonLinearBlockGS` solver actually needs to run the tools in the coupled system two times per iteration. These runs originate from the `self._iter_execute()` and the `self._run_apply()` in the `_run_iterator()` method of the solver (class `Solver` in file `solver.py`).

My main question is, are two runs per iteration really required, and if so, why?

It seems the first component run (`self.iter_execute()`) uses an initial guess for the feedback variables that need to be converged and then runs the components sequentially while updating any feedforward data. This is the step I would expect for Gauss-Seidel. But then the second component run (`self._run_apply()`) runs the components again with the updated feedback variables that resulted from the first run while keeping the feedforwards as they were in that first run. If I'm not mistaken, this information is then (only) used to assess the convergence of that iteration (`self._iter_get_norm()`).

Instead of having this second run inside the iteration, wouldn't it be more efficient to directly continue to the next iteration? In that iteration we can use the new values of the feedback variables and do another `self._iter_execute()` with the update of feedforward data and then assess the convergence based on the difference between the results between those two iterations. Of course this means that we need at least two iterations to assess convergence, but it saves one component run per iteration. (This is actually the existing implementation that I have for convergence of these components in MATLAB and that works as expected, hence it finds the same converged design, but with half the amount of component runs.)

So another way of putting this is: why do we need the `self._run_apply()` in each iteration when doing Gauss-Seidel convergence? (And could this be turned off?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of different aspects to your question. First, I'll address the details of `solve_nonlinear` vs `apply_nonlinear`. With underlying mathematical algorithms of OpenMDAO, based on the [MAUD framework](http://mdolab.engin.umich.edu/content/computational-architecture-coupling-heterogeneous-numerical-models-and-computing-coupled) , `solve_nonlinear` computes the values of the output values only (does not set residuals). `apply_nonlinear` computes only the residuals (and does not set outputs). 
For sub-classes of `ExplicitComponent`, the user only implements a `compute` method, and the base class implements both `solve_nonlinear` and `apply_nonlinear` using `compute`.

As you described it, in OpenMDAO V2.4 current implementation of NonlinearBlockGaussSeidel for each iteration, performs one recursive `solve_nonlinear` call on its group and then calls `apply_nonlinear` to check the residual and look for convergence.

However, you're also correct that we could be doing this more efficiently. The modification you suggested to the algorithm would work, and we'll put it on the development pipeline for for V2.6 (as of the time of this post, we're just about to release V2.5 and there won't be time to add this into that release)